# linking a .proto file using qmake

Tags: qt, protocol-buffers

I have 4 files

message.proto
udp.h
udp.cpp
main.cpp

message.proto is a google protocol buffer file. I am trying to write a protocol buffer and send and receive data using UDP. udp.h and udp.cpp are just classes to implement UDP.

I can write my own makefile and do the needful for this small example. Later I would require to integrate this code into my QT program. I am using qmake -project, qmake to generate the Makefile. I am using Ubuntu 9.10

Could some one tell me the changes I need to make in the .pro file or the Makefile generated by qmake to satisfy the dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you just need to add the respective header and source files to the corresponding `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` variables in the .pro file, i.e.

```
SOURCES += udp.cpp message.pb.cc
HEADERS += udp.h message.pb.h
```

where I implicity assumed that message.pb.cc and message.pb.h are the files generated by `protoc` (the protocol buffer compiler). If you additionally want the generated makefile to run `protoc` for you, you can accomplish that with the `system` function (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command).

I hope that helps.

Comment: This comes automatically when i run the command qmake -project
After this i run qmake to get the Makefile
on executing the makefile i get loads of errors. I am guessing the protoc library is not getting included. Can someone tell me where and how to include the protoc library in the makefile or pro file generated by qmake

Comment: You accepted this as your answer, but as you stated in the comments, there's still a linker issue, how did you deal with this?